# SUM in select interfering with results

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to select data from two tables: users and rentals. There may be many rentals per single user and I want to get all users as result, even the ones with zero rentals. Trick is, I also want a sum of user's all rentals, and this seems to be interfering with the results. With the query as shown below, I'm only getting users with rentals as results, the users without rentals are not included. And with extra filtering, there are cases where I'm getting results full of NULL values. How can I include the sum without messing up the results?

```
SELECT u.*, r.*, SUM(r.rental_id) AS totalRentals, (SELECT rented From rentals WHERE rentals.rental_id = u.user_id ORDER BY rented DESC LIMIT 1) as lastRental FROM users u LEFT JOIN rentals r on u.user_id = r.user_id ORDER BY u.surname DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the simplest solution is to group the results by users.user_id, which correctly returns all users, including the ones for whom the SUM column returns zero:

```
SELECT u.*, r.*, SUM(r.rental_id) AS totalRentals, (SELECT rented From rentals WHERE rentals.rental_id = u.user_id ORDER BY rented DESC LIMIT 1) as lastRental FROM users u LEFT JOIN rentals r on u.user_id = r.user_id GROUP BY u.user_id
```

Really appreciate getting downwoted, that's exactly what I came here for.